# Can't post node that requires a pre assigned value with services api

Tags: rest, drupal, service, content-type

I have setup a content type with a subject field that has pre assigned values in a dropdown field.
I am using the services api to post new content from a polymer app.
When I POST to the api I send the field structure and value in json but get and error.

"406 (Not Acceptable : An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.)"

Even though the object I am sending matches one of the required values in the field.

Do I need to prefix the value with something? I assume I'm posting to the right place to get that response but don't know why it would accept anything other than the string value.

Here is what I sent to the api which is picked up by my Charles proxy.

`{
    "node": {
        "type": "case",
        "title": "my case",
        "language": "und",
        "field_subject": {
            "und": {
                "0": {
                    "value": "subject1"
                }
            }
        },
        "body": {
            "und": {
                "0": {
                    "value": "my details of subject"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

And here is an example of what I have setup in my Drupal field

`subject1| first
subject2| second
subject3| third
subject4| forth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else with the same problem, this subject is poorly documented, but the answer is simple, my subject did not need the value key despite devel suggesting thats how it would be formatted.

`"field_subject": {
    "und": [ 
        "subject1"
    ]
}`

I could also shorten my code with "und" being an array.

Comment: Oh wow, I struggled so much with this issue. I am using jDrupal, and with your code, I can finally save fields.