# Android and Drupal. How to post this value, is it a Boolean or Int?

Tags: android, post, drupal, http-post

I am using Drupal as a backend and Android as a font-end. I want to post a value (field_top_problem) from Android.

My Problem. 
I am not sure which value it should POST (Int, String, Bool ect)?
I have tried a few time but had no success.

I keep getting this error message: An illegal choice has been detected.

All the other values are posted correctly. Its just this one (field_top_problem), I am struggeling with.

In Drupal, **field_top_problem** is a radio button with **Yes** (value:1) and **No** (value:0). 
 Field type is set to Boolean
[image]

In postman it looks like this:

```
"field_top_problem": {"und": [{"value": "1"}]},
```

Everything else post's, when i remove the field_top_problem.

My code

```
 //Test value for input
 public String val1 = "1";
 public String val2 = "1";
```

Input fields, i am posting

```
String input = ("{ \"title\":\""+title+"\"," +
"\"type\":\"ocd_problem\"," +
"\"status\":\"1\"," +
"\"field_top_problem\":{\"und\":[{ \"value\":\""+val1+"\"}]}," +
"\"field_difficulty\":{\"und\":[{ \"value\":\""+val2+"\"}]}}");
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
I had to change it to.

```
"\"field_top_problem\":{\"und\":[\""+val1+"\"]}," +
```

Its weird that in Postman it looked different.

```
"field_top_problem": {"und": [{"value": "1"}]},
```

Just a quick question, where do you guys go, to find out the json format for posting? I used Postman, but in my case Postman was wrong.

I found this on Stackoverflow. Its not exactly like my problem but it helped to solve my issue.

[Can't post node that requires a pre assigned value with services api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671074/cant-post-node-that-requires-a-pre-assigned-value-with-services-api)

Hope this helps someone else